# Jquery append overwrite same element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem to append to same element. The problem is i have 2 cases:

```
if (lastIndexOfUnderscore < 0){ //list priv (no parent)
        $("<a href='#' class='list-group-item'></a>").text(items.name).appendTo($div);
} else {
        $("<a href='#' class='list-group-item'></a>").text(items.name).appendTo($div);
}
```

I want the ui to be `'no parent'` in one `div` and `'else'` on other `div`.

I already try `.clone()` but still cant figure it.

Here is the code..https://jsfiddle.net/zofeqjm1/

Comment: `on other div`  where?

Comment: I have no clue what you want, could you try to explain another way?
Do you want 'RE02_RE04_RE05' to be nested in 'RE02_RE04' and that one in 'RE02' or?

Comment: Other div mean i new to create new div for each cases so i will have multiple <div> contain <a>

Comment: @JaiGtz Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/zofeqjm1/2/

Comment: @sniels i just want all that have parentId must be in other div

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy's fiddle seems to do just that

Comment: @Rajaprabhu That will be same like i create new div right? like i mention before that each contain parentid must have own div..more like a navigation menu flyout..

Comment: So you mean those have `parentId` must be under the parent. @JaiGtz

Comment: @Azim Yes..thats all would help much..

Comment: @Azim No. It should be 3 div only. RE01 and RE02 (div1), RE03 and RE04 (div2) and RE05 (div3)..

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/zofeqjm1/4/ ?

Comment: @Azim Yes..Thanks a lot..sorry for my bad explanation.. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like following. Add a `div` with `id = parentId` if the `item` has `parentId`. If a `div` with `parentId` already exist then add the `item` to the `div`.

```
$.each(sample.item, function (i, items) {
    if (items.parentId) {
        if ($('#' + items.parentId).length) {
            $('#' + items.parentId).append('<a href=# class=list-group-item>' + items.name + '</a>');
        } else {
            $('.priv').append('<div id=' + items.parentId + '><a href=# class=list-group-item>' + items.name + '</a></div>');
        }
    } else { //list priv (no parent)
        $('.privList').append('<a href=# class=list-group-item>' + items.name + '</a>');
    }
});
```

#### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zofeqjm1/4/)